# Создание кнопки и подключение стилей программно

Tags: java, android, xml

Ситуация такова:
Я загружаю несколько строк текста из файла и помещаю его в массив. После я создаю цикл длиной этого массива и в нем создаю кнопки такой вот конструкцией:

```
Button btn = new Button (new ContextThemeWrapper (this, R.style.startBtn));
```

И добавляю в уже готовый LinearLayout эти кнопки через **addView**

Кнопки добавились и стили вроде бы тоже, но сами стили работают от части. То есть не работает **background textColor** и некоторые другие, не мало важные стили.

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поработать с RecyclerView и Adapter-ами для них. Кажется, это подходит под вашу задачу, и будет удобнее.